# Check for definition GNU C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, c-preprocessor, shared

I'm trying to find out a little bit more about how the preprocessor works in relation to shared object libraries generated by GCC on GNU/Linux.

I've been unable to find a clear, concise answer to this.

If I use preprocessor statements like:

```
#ifndef __OPTI_MY_VARIABLE
#define __OPTI_MY_VARIABLE 1
#endif
```

And I compile a shared object file with this and link to it with another program in which I declare:

```
#define __OPTI_MY_VARIABLE 2
```

Will my program then use the value 1 or 2 after compiling the main program which uses the shared object library?

If it uses the value 1, is there a way to construct the code such that it will use the value 2, for example by not using pre-processor statements? In other words, is there a way for me to declare default values unless another global variable by the same name overrides it, or must this info be passed to the function in the shared object?

Comment: From **7.1.3 Reserved identifiers**: "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use."

Comment: On my 64bit Debian unstable running gcc 4.6.1, I get a warning for redefining the macro but in the end it takes on the value 2.  By reading the code, it appears the macro will take the value 2 all the time.  Nothing should have stopped you from doing this yourself.  Was this the question or am I missing something?

Comment: I've been doing some testing, and it takes the value 2 if I compile the whole thing at once, but if I make a dynamic or static library and compile that, then use that library in my other code, it takes the value 1.

Confusing...

But I've found a way to do it. I define global variables the first time the header is included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#define`s are only seen by the preprocessor.  The preprocessor runs completely before the compiler.  The compiler runs before linking.

If you want to be able to override the default value "inside" your shared object, then I would suggest using a setter function, and a static global variable, e.g.:

```
#define OPTI_MY_VARIABLE_DEFAULT   1

static int opti_my_variable = OPTI_MY_VARIABLE_DEFAULT;

...

void set_opti_my_variable(int i) { opti_my_variable = i; }
```

Obviously, this uses a global variable, which many people frown upon...

Comment: Thank you. This answers the first question.

However, it doesn't answer what I can do instead. Can I do anything?

Answer (score 0):

The question is wrong.

Those defines mean that in the source code all occurances of the define name are replaced by the value given, *prior to compilation*.

So in one shared library, where-ever you had that name, you have the value 1.  In the other, the value 2.  That name does not as such exist in the shared libraries.  If you use both shared libraries with a single programme, then whatever variables in the first library which were set the define name will have the value 1 and in the second library, the value 2.